# What files in a Cargo project should be in my .gitignore?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I created a "hello world" Rust app using `cargo new`. When I executed `git status` it showed a bunch of files:

```
A  rust/welcomec/Cargo.lock
A  rust/welcomec/Cargo.toml
A  rust/welcomec/src/main.rs
A  rust/welcomec/target/debug/.cargo-lock
A  rust/welcomec/target/debug/.fingerprint/welcomec-2d68725c8fae6fd1/bin-welcome-2d68725c8fae6fd1
A  rust/welcomec/target/debug/.fingerprint/welcomec-2d68725c8fae6fd1/bin-welcome-2d68725c8fae6fd1.json
A  rust/welcomec/target/debug/.fingerprint/welcomec-2d68725c8fae6fd1/dep-bin-welcome-2d68725c8fae6fd1
A  rust/welcomec/target/debug/deps/welcome-2d68725c8fae6fd1
A  rust/welcomec/target/debug/welcome
A  rust/welcomec/target/debug/welcome.d
```

Can I safely ignore any of these files and/or directories?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## Summary

#### `.gitignore` for executable crates

```
# Generated files
/target/
```

#### `.gitignore` for library crates

```
# Generated files
/target/

# Well, this depends... See below!
Cargo.lock
```

---

## Details

You can always ignore the `target/` folder completely. It only contains generated files (e.g. compile artifacts) and is also usually quite large.

If you are developing an executable program, then that's it already! Just a single entry.

For library projects, you may also want to ignore `Cargo.lock`. But this is a bit more nuanced. The official stance on that matter [was changed recently](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2023/08/29/committing-lockfiles.html). `Cargo.lock` enables reproducible builds as it records the exact version of all dependencies. This is very useful. For executables you absolutely want those reproducible builds, hence the recommendation above.

It is important to understand that if a project uses your library, your `Cargo.lock` is ignored! Cargo only cares about `Cargo.toml` of dependencies. So whether `Cargo.lock` is in your repository is basically only relevant for your development of the library.

- On the one hand, you should always test your library with the latest version of all your dependencies. That's an argument against `Cargo.lock`.
- On the other hand, `Cargo.lock` gives you the same benefit as in other projects: reproducible builds mean stable CI, easier bisecting, yada yada.

In the end, you decide. But be assured: you can't really screw it up. Either way is usually fine.

---

And note: `cargo new` should already create an appropriate `.gitignore` file for you.

Comment: One thing I'd add is if you're creating a subdirectory inside an existing git repository it won't generate the .gitignore file automatically

Answer (score 7):

You can take some inspiration from [GitHub's gitignore for Rust](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rust.gitignore). At the time of writing, the file goes as follows:

```sh
# Generated by Cargo
# will have compiled files and executables
debug/
target/

# Remove Cargo.lock from gitignore if creating an executable, leave it for libraries
# More information here https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/cargo-toml-vs-cargo-lock.html
Cargo.lock

# These are backup files generated by rustfmt
**/*.rs.bk

# MSVC Windows builds of rustc generate these, which store debugging information
*.pdb
```